# How do i create a virtual folder in my microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709 image

Tags: asp.net, iis, dockerfile

I have this simple default Dockerfile that i'm using:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

And i'm trying to publish my in a subfolder in wwwroot, because my application is hardcoded to use a virtual folder, but it seems this is outside the scope of Docker's capabilities. At least for Windows.

If i try things like changing the WORKDIR to /inetpub/wwwroot/subfolder, it fails bringing up the app with:

> Recreating dockercompose16651484078226882483_dotnetwebappdocker_1 ... 
>   Recreating dockercompose16651484078226882483_dotnetwebappdocker_1 ...
>   error ERROR: for
>   dockercompose16651484078226882483_dotnetwebappdocker_1  Cannot start
>   service dotnetwebappdocker: container
>   e6d05a411cb22028ab2a855eaafdfab541f81f3b47ebe7255ee5ddcd31b774f9
>   encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call:
>   The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106) ERROR: for
>   dotnetwebappdocker  Cannot start service dotnetwebappdocker: container
>   e6d05a411cb22028ab2a855eaafdfab541f81f3b47ebe7255ee5ddcd31b774f9
>   encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call:
>   The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106) Encountered
>   errors while bringing up the project..

Ultimately i want to publish two applications in my wwwroot, an /app/ and an /auth/ but i need one to work before adding another :)

Any help out there?

Comment: Any luck with this? Looking at the same issue.

Comment: @Forklift afraid not